# How can we multiply each elements of an array to each other and store each product values in a array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, multiplication

example: let's say we have an array of arr1 [1,2,3,4] , the products will be 1x2, 1x3, 1x4, 2x1, 2x3, 2x4, 3x1, 3x2, 3x4, 4x1, 4x, 4x3. so the new array will be like arr2 [2,3,4,2,6,8,3,6,12,4,8,12].
I thought about going with :

```
for( int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
       arr2[i]= arr1[j] * arr1[j+1];
    }
}
```

But that only multiplies consecutive elements and not all.
Can someone tell me the logic/algorithm?

Comment: Sounds like you need nested loops. Also "a for loop with i=0 to n and i++ { arr2[i]= arr1[i] *arr[i+1]; }" Wouldn't it be easier to actually show the loop?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. For one, you mix the actual requirements and implementation details. If you need only unique products then is it really necessary to store them in an array?

Comment: ok i added the code. i know the logic isnot right. it means we need to find out the products of each elements with each other and then store it in other array first. i can get rid of the duplicates. but i am stuck at the first part.

Comment: *i can get rid of the duplicates* -- Something seems strange -- the easy part is the multiplication, to be honest with you.  It is the removal of the duplicates that's the tougher job or at least takes more thought.

Comment: _so the final array will be arr2[2,3,4,6,8,12]._ Storing your multiply results in a `std::set`, you will get the sorting and removal of duplicates for free.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 -- That's my point.  I don't know of a new programmer who would automatically go (and use) `std::unique`, but get stumped by a simple nested `for` loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie imagine a world where beginners get thaught algorithms before loops, iterators before pointers, `std::string` before c-strings,.....

Comment: how can i multiply each element with each other first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `if` statement to check that `i != j` before doing the multiplication.

You also need another index variable to hold the index in the output array, you can't use `i` for this, since it stops at `n`. You also can't use `i*n + j` because you're skipping elements (there may be a formula for the desired index, but using another variable is simpler).

```
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (i != j) {
            arr2[k++] = arr1[i] * arr1[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can provide the [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e44f4786887ff82). Uh, no! It still removes the duplicates - sorry. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff frankly, removing duplicates after putting each entry twice is a little.... silly. Inner loop should start at `i+1`, though that wouldn't meet the updated goal

Comment: @idclev463035818 The question says he wants 2x1, so the inner loop needs to start back at 0

Comment: @idclev463035818 I must admit I wouldn't let go it into productive code if it could be traced back to my real name.

Comment: @Barmar I am still refering to the old post to which Scheff also refers. Sorry, I will shut up now :P

Comment: @Scheff thanks for the code. i can't believe the solution was this simple.